# Selecting Only the most recent date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I'm having difficulties with a query that absolutely has me stumped.  I have a mysql database for a restaurant chain that keeps track of menu item prices from year to year.  In this particular query I'm trying to obtain only the most recent price for an item at each store.

```
ItemMenu
pk  storeNum itemNum vendorNum  size    price   year
1   5555     2000    3150       Large   3.99    2015
2   5555     2000    3150       Large   3.75    2014
3   3333     2000    3153       Large   3.69    2014
4   2222     2000    3150       Large   3.89    2014
5   2222     2000    3150       Large   3.69    2013


  ItemList
itemNum item            categoryNum
2000    Mashed Potatoes 2000
2001    Green Beans     2000
2002    Coleslaw        2000
2003    Baked Beans     2000
2004    Corn            2000

ItemCategory    
categoryNum type
2000        Side
2001        Dessert
2002        Drink
2003        Sauce

ItemVendor  
vendorNum   vendorName
3150        Acme Foods
3152        John's Vegetables
3153        Smith's Wholesale

Stores          
storeNum    franchisee    address        phone
5555        David Smith   9999 Main st   555-1212 
3333        James Bond    123 Baker      867-5309
2222        Mark Jones    450 21st Ave   888-5411
```

What I would like to have returned is

storeNum, franchisee, item, type, vendorName, size, price, year 
But only for the most recent year.

```
5555, David Smith, Mashed Potatoes, Side, Acme Foods, Large, 3.99, 2015
3333, James Bond,  Mashed Potatoes, Side, Smith's Wholesale, 3.69, 2014
2222, Mark Jones,  Mashed Potatoes, Side, Acme Foods, Large, 3.89, 2014
```

I hope that made sense, I'm at a complete loss of how to join the multiple tables and only pulling data for the most recent year.

Thanks,

Kevin

I have this working but have run into another issue where I may have multiple prices for a given year due to a mid-year price increase.  How can I go about adding an additional sub-query to grab the max price after I've selected the max year?

My current query

```
SELECT m.storeNum, m.itemNum,size,m.price,year FROM ItemMenu m,    
(SELECT storeNum, itemNum, MAX(year) maxYear FROM ItemMenu
GROUP BY storeNum, itemNum) yt, (SELECT storeNum, itemNum, MAX(price)        
maxPrice FROM ItemMenu) mp 
WHERE m.storeNum=yt.storeNum AND m.itemNum=yt.itemNum 
AND m.year=yt.maxYear AND m.itemNum=5000 AND m.storeNum=205706;
```

Returns valid results for max  year (I've selected a specific store and item to reduce the number of results).

```
+----------+---------+------------+-------+------+
| storeNum | itemNum | size       | price | year |
+----------+---------+------------+-------+------+
|   205706 |    5000 | Individual |  1.59 | 2014 |
|   205706 |    5000 | Large      |  3.69 | 2014 |
|   205706 |    5000 | Large      |  3.59 | 2014 |
|   205706 |    5000 | Individual |  1.79 | 2014 |
+----------+---------+------------+-------+------+
```

I need to further reduce this so I only get the values of $1.79 and 3.69.

Thanks

-Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a subquery: 1st get a set of the most recent year for a given `(item,store)` pairing.  Next, select the price for that `(item,store,year)` triplet:

```
SELECT m.storeNum, m.itemNum,price,year FROM ItemMenu m,
    (SELECT storeNum, itemNum, MAX(year) maxYear FROM ItemMenu 
        GROUP BY storeNum, itemNum) yt
    WHERE m.storeNum=yt.storeNum AND m.itemNum=yt.itemNum 
          AND m.year=yt.maxYear;
```

You can, of course, join the various ID->name tables onto this to get the human-readable data, but I suspect your issue was figuring out how to get the most recent prices.

It should be also noted that this could be done with a `JOIN` rather than including the subquery in the `FROM` section; that may be faster.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the using the JOIN rather than the subquery?  This particular query could easily return tens of thousands of results and efficiency is preferred.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, please elaborate on the join vs from. What your code does is a join. It's just an old style (pre ANSI 92). So what do you mean?

Comment: @kevinfwb , @HoneyBadger sorry if that was misleading -- You would still be using a subquery; the difference is in the `FROM a,b` vs `FROM a JOIN b` syntax.  Which, as @HoneyBadger pointed out, was technically a join in the first place.

Comment: Ah yes that does make much more sense. Would there be a performance difference between the two styles though? I'd think it's translated to the same thing under the hood, and get the same execution plan.

Comment: @zebediah49 @HoneyBadger  I stepped away from this for a while but I'm just not getting back to it.  I have it working where I get the max year but I've run into another issue where there may be multiple prices for a given year where I also need to max. `code`

Comment: I think  you can just adjust `m.price` to `MAX(m.price)`, and add a `GROUP BY  m.storeNum, m.itemNum,size,year` to the outer query to collapse the multiple prices.